# Safe and polymorphic toEnum

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I'd like to write a safe version of `toEnum`:

```
 safeToEnum :: (Enum t, Bounded t) => Int -> Maybe t
```

A naive implementation:

```
safeToEnum :: (Enum t, Bounded t) => Int -> Maybe t
safeToEnum i =
  if (i >= fromEnum (minBound :: t)) && (i <= fromEnum (maxBound :: t))
    then Just . toEnum $ i
    else Nothing

main = do
  print $ (safeToEnum 1 :: Maybe Bool)
  print $ (safeToEnum 2 :: Maybe Bool)
```

And it doesn't work:

```
safeToEnum.hs:3:21:
    Could not deduce (Bounded t1) from the context ()
      arising from a use of `minBound' at safeToEnum.hs:3:21-28
    Possible fix:
      add (Bounded t1) to the context of an expression type signature
    In the first argument of `fromEnum', namely `(minBound :: t)'
    In the second argument of `(>=)', namely `fromEnum (minBound :: t)'
    In the first argument of `(&&)', namely
        `(i >= fromEnum (minBound :: t))'

safeToEnum.hs:3:56:
    Could not deduce (Bounded t1) from the context ()
      arising from a use of `maxBound' at safeToEnum.hs:3:56-63
    Possible fix:
      add (Bounded t1) to the context of an expression type signature
    In the first argument of `fromEnum', namely `(maxBound :: t)'
    In the second argument of `(<=)', namely `fromEnum (maxBound :: t)'
    In the second argument of `(&&)', namely
        `(i <= fromEnum (maxBound :: t))'
```

As well as I understand the message, the compiler does not recognize that `minBound` and `maxBound` should produce exactly the same type as in the result type of `safeToEnum` inspite of the explicit type declaration (`:: t`). Any idea how to fix it?

---

**Solved**

Both camccann's and Dave's solutions work (though Dave's one needs to be adjusted). Thank you both (but I could accept only one). Working example with ScopedTypeVariables:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

safeToEnum :: forall t . (Enum t, Bounded t) => Int -> Maybe t
safeToEnum i =
  if (i >= fromEnum (minBound :: t)) && (i <= fromEnum (maxBound :: t))
    then Just . toEnum $ i
    else Nothing
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scoped type variables aren't necessary here, you just need to make it clear to GHC that you expect all the `Enum` stuff to be the same type. This is easy to do by passing them all to a function that explicitly takes various `Enum`s of the same type. Here's one way:

```
enumIfBetween :: (Enum a) => a -> a -> Int -> Maybe a
enumIfBetween a z x = let a' = fromEnum a
                          z' = fromEnum z
                      in if a' <= x && x <= z'
                         then Just $ toEnum x
                         else Nothing

safeToEnum i = enumIfBetween minBound maxBound i

main = do
    print $ (safeToEnum 1 :: Maybe Bool)
    print $ (safeToEnum 2 :: Maybe Bool)
```

Trying it in GHCi:

```
> main
Just True
Nothing
```

A more general solution using the same principle is the standard library function `asTypeOf`, which has the same behavior as `const` but requires both arguments to be the same type:

```
safeToEnum :: (Enum t, Bounded t) => Int -> Maybe t
safeToEnum i = let r = toEnum i
                   max = maxBound `asTypeOf` r
                   min = minBound `asTypeOf` r
               in if i >= fromEnum min && i <= fromEnum max
               then Just r
               else Nothing
```

This version works as well.

Keep in mind that `ScopedTypeVariables` is a language extension, and thus not necessarily portable between compilers. In practice almost everyone uses GHC, but it's usually preferred to stick to the standard base language (i.e., Haskell 98) when possible. In this case, `ScopedTypeVariables` really is overkill; the [Haskell wiki suggests `asTypeOf` as a portable replacement](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables) for this kind of scenario.

Comment: I like your solutions. It's very nice that `r` is not actually evaluated in `asTypeOf` (second version).

Comment: @jetxee: Well, it's certainly evaluated if you actually *use* it... which of course won't happen if the result is `Nothing`. Ain't it great to be lazy?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use scoped type variables

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

safeToEnum :: (Enum t, Bounded t) => Int -> Maybe t
safeToEnum i =
  if (i >= fromEnum (minBound :: t)) && (i <= fromEnum (maxBound :: t))
    then Just . toEnum $ i
    else Nothing

main = do
  print $ (safeToEnum 1 :: Maybe Bool)
  print $ (safeToEnum 2 :: Maybe Bool)
```

Without it, `t` means `forall t. t`.

Comment: Still getting `Could not deduce (Bounded t1) from the context ()`. GHC 6.12.1.

Comment: OK. This works: `safeToEnum :: forall t . (Enum t, Bounded t) => Int -> Maybe t`. Thank you.

Comment: You can work around the need to use scoped type variables by adding a helper combinator like: asArgTypeOf :: a -> f a -> a; asArgTypeOf = const and and plumbing it through like safeToEnum i = r where r = ... and using (minBound `asArgTypeOf` r) and (maxBound `asArgTypeOf` r).